# Reactjs - How to create a JSON with list Child Object?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, post, axios

I have JSON structure like this

```
    "timebought": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
    "totalCost": 3000.0,
    "address": "ABC",
    "status": false,
    "customersEmail":"nguyenvana@gmail.com",
    "orderDetails": [
        {
            "productId": "A1",
            "amount": 5   
        },
        {
            "productId": "A2",
            "amount": 5   
        }
    ]
```

If I want make a JSON for post, how do i do it? I mean the child object "orderDetails", can you give me an example?

Comment: For post? Do you mean a post request? What is wrong with this one? Why can't you use it like this?

Comment: @MikaelsSlava I want make a JSON like this, i dont know how to make it

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `react.js`, how do you collect `orderDetails` on front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it:
First, make a function return list Child:

```
function toArr(){
  let arr = [];
prodList.forEach((prod) => {
   let item ={"id":prod.id,"amount" : prod.quantity};
   arr = [...arr,item];
  });
  console.log(arr);
  return arr;}
```

and then

```
const body = JSON.stringify({
    customersEmail : e.target.email.value,
    totalCost : totalCost.current,
    status : false,
    address: e.target.address.value,
    orderDetails: toArr()
});
```